# vagrant ubuntu/xenial64 win10 vagrant 1.9.4 Destroying VM and associated drives

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am on windows 10 
Vagrant and Virtualbox are installed i do this in cmd
vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64

vagrant up --provider virtualbox

and get this :/ any suggestions what i can do?

```
> ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
>     default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2207
>     default: SSH username: ubuntu
>     default: SSH auth method: password
> ==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
> ==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives... C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:54:in
> `readpartial': Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuertdurch
> den Hostcomputer abgebrochen. (Errno::ECONNABORTED)   from
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:54:in
> `block (2 levels) in negotiate!'  from
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:52:in
> `loop'    from
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:52:in
> `block in negotiate!'     from
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:50:in
> `loop'    from
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-
>...more error messages...
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. What version of Vagrant?

Comment: its version 1.9.4.. there is a newer version. will test it.

Comment: yes i can confirm that this a vagrant bug, but has been fixed in 1.9.5

Comment: can confirm for me self update helped. thx